# Is there any way to force browser to refresh when the site had "pragma: cache"?

Tags: php, html, caching, header, pragma

I have once wrongly set as `pragma: cache` header on my website, and now I have turned it back to `Pragma: no-cache`, but I am still receiving reports that people don't see the updates on my site.

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want the users to see without force refresh. If it is the standard JS and CSS files. Do something like below -

**JS**

```
<script src="file.js?version=<?php echo $random_number;?>"></script>
```

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo $random_number;?>" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Using filemtime instead of random number is better, but the server code has to be able to reach the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think no-cache is not enough.. add the following too.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Sat, 31 Oct 2014 00:00:00 GMT">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

You can use the code below to refresh or reload the currently loaded index page from a URL address entered directly into the browser's address bar, after a specific number of seconds, thereby forcing the browser to always reload the current document. In this case, the number of seconds has been set to 5:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

Please note that setting the number of seconds to 0 will cause the page to be automatically reloaded instantly, every time it is successfully downloaded.

Read this article too : [Pragma: No-cache" Tag May Not Prevent Page from Being Cached](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/222064/-pragma-no-cache-tag-may-not-prevent-page-from-being-cached)